# Reverse for 'user-blog' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pages/user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$'] in django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to create a Userpostlistview in to my blog post,which you can see all post by a specific user i have them created but i get to see this error everytime i go to my blog url [image: this is is error in picture]

i only get to see the error when i identify the user in the template this is my code

### views.py

```
class CustomUserBlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'pages/user_blog.html' 
    context_object_name = 'blog_post'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Blog.objects.filter(doctor=user.doctor).order_by('-timestamp')
```

### urls.py

```
    path('user/<str:username>', CustomUserBlogListView.as_view(), name='user-blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/update/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='blog-update'),
    path('blog/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='blog-create'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='blog-delete'),
    path('doctor_info/', user_views.doctor_info, name='doctor_info'),
    path('patient/', user_views.patient, name='patient'),
```

### blog.html

```
{% for blog in blog_post %}
          <div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">
            <div class="blog-entry "> 
              <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="block-20" style="background-image: url({{ blog.image.url }})"></a>
              <div class="text d-block">
                <div class="meta mb-3">
                  <div>{{ blog.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                  <div><a href="{% url 'user-blog' blog.doctor.username %}">Written By {{ blog.doctor.user.username }}</a></div>
                  <div><a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-eye"></span>{{ blog.view_count }}</a></div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="heading"><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}">{{ blog.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

### user_blog.html

```
 <h1 class="mb-3"> {{ view.kwargs.username }} has ({{ page_obj.paginator.count }}) Post</h1>
    {% for blog in blog_post %}
 <section class="ftco-section bg-light" id="blog-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-10 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Gets Every Single Updates Here</h2>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
          </div>
        </div>
   {% if user.doctor %}
  <a class="btn btn-outline-danger center button" href="{% url 'blog-create' %}">Create a Blog</a>
       {% else %}
       {% endif %}
       <br><p></p>
        <div class="row d-flex">
         {% for blog in blog_post %}
          <div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">
            <div class="blog-entry "> 
              <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="block-20" style="background-image: url({{ blog.image.url }})"></a>
              <div class="text d-block">
                <div class="meta mb-3">
                  <div>{{ blog.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                  <div class="h6 btn"><a href="{% url 'user-blog' blog.doctor.user.username %}"> Written By {{ blog.doctor.user.username }}</a></div>
                  <div><a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-eye"></span>{{ blog.view_count }}</a></div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="heading"><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}">{{ blog.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you add you model field as well. I want to see weather you are using the right fields in you template.

Comment: thanks i have solved  my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually  when coding you need to check spacing,i had spacing in my html,i delete it and write it again